# NodeJS v8.getHeapSpaceStatistics() meaning

Tags: node.js, memory, v8

I'm learning about memory management of chrome v8 engine,

```
const v8 = require('v8');

console.log(v8.getHeapSpaceStatistics())
```

what does `read_only_space`、`map_space` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are different parts of V8's managed heap. As their names imply, `read_only_space` is for read-only data (and should have constant size throughout the lifecycle of your app), and `map_space` is for what V8 internally calls "maps" (a.k.a. "shape descriptors" or "hidden classes"; note this has nothing to do with a JavaScript `new Map()`). Most of your app's memory usage will be in `old_space`, and possibly `large_object_space` if you allocate very large objects.